# React-Redux. I can view my array in state but cant map over it

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I can see that projects exist when I log it but trying to call map gives me an undefined error

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Project from "./Project";

const ProjectsContainer = ({ projects }) => {
  const allProjects = projects.map((project, index) => (
    <Project key={index} project={project} />
  ));
  return <div></div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    projects: state.projects,
    loggedIn: !!state.currentUser
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProjectsContainer);
```

UPDATE
this happens after I log in. I get `TypeError: projects.map is not a function`
But if I refresh the page it works

Comment: What is the error and why are you generating jxs in map state to props?

Comment: ```Uncaught TypeError: projects.map is not a function```
I was trying to various ways to troubleshoot.

Comment: That implies that projects is something (not falsey), but it isn't an array. Are you sure it isn't an Object or something else? Try doing a `console.log` on it before you assign `allProjects` and see what state.projects actually is.

Comment: I get the expected result when I console log. Also, the array is in the redux store with all the objects inside

Comment: Does your "expected result" also include `projects` being null? If so, that's your problem. Your previous code allowed `projects` to be null. I'm not sure if your component tried to map over that or not.

Comment: make this check `{loggedIn && projects.length > 0 ? projects.map()` : null}

Comment: In mapStateToProps you can do `projects: state.projects || []`

Comment: expected result will be an empty array if no projects exist

Comment: ```{loggedIn && projects.length > 0 ? projects.map() : null} ```
```projects: state.projects || []```
Doing both of those seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Project from "./Project";

const ProjectsContainer = ({ projects =[] }) => {
  const allProjects = projects.map((project, index) => (
    <Project key={index} project={project} />
  ));
  return <div></div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    projects: state.projects,
    loggedIn: !!state.currentUser
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProjectsContainer);
```

Comment: I am getting ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null```
on trying to assign getprojects. I am still able to see projects in the store which is an array of Objects

Comment: can you share your screenshot of console window like console.log(state)

Comment: I have modified your code , please try above code. Added default value to projects = []

Comment: a default value with a size check seems to have fixed it.TY

Comment: @Ricardo mark the answer as resolved if it fixed your issue.